# Wallpaper doesn't rotate or stretch to match the screen when in landscape mode

Tags: wallpaper, auto-rotation

I have a Samsung Stratosphere, running Android 2.3.6. My problem is that when I'm on the home screen and I slide the keyboard out (putting the device into landscape mode), the wallpaper does not change with the rest of screen. For the purposes of illustration, I've made a home screen less cluttered than my real one, and used a wallpaper whose orientation can be more easily discerned ([see here for the full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFQ0m.jpg)). Click on the screenshots below for larger versions.

[image]           [image]

As you can see, the wallpaper doesn't rotate to match the orientation of the screen, nor does it stretch; there are just some (very silly looking) black bars.

I owned a Stratosphere for a few years, during which I never had this problem with the wallpaper; however, the wallpaper I used during this time was just an image consisting of just a solid color, so I can't say for sure whether the wallpaper was being rotated or stretched. All I know is that I never had any black bars. But I recently dropped it and had to get a replacement via my Asurion insurance policy, and now an ostensibly identical device has this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem with Android 4.3 on a Samsung tablet and have the same problem. It's really stupid.